# Unable to enable chrome shelf in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a chrome extension where the default popup works as a download shelf. So as soon as the popup opens I am disabling the shelf using

```
chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(false);
```

But now when I try to enable the shelf when the popup is closed, Nothing is happening. And there is no error on the console.

```
var backgroundPage = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();  
  addEventListener("unload", function (event) {
            chrome.downloads.setShelfEnabled(true);
            backgroundPage.console.log(event.type);         
    }, true);
```

I had to reload the plugin every time to enable it. Any help on how to enable the shelf would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads#method-setShelfEnabled): Enable or disable the gray shelf at the bottom of every window associated with the current browser profile. The shelf will be disabled as long as at least one extension has disabled it. Enabling the shelf while at least one other extension has disabled it will return an error through runtime.lastError. Requires the "downloads.shelf" permission in addition to the "downloads" permission.

Try to include '*onChanged*' events, this event fires with the downloadId and an object containing the properties that changed.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out. But this counts as an answer.